# Connect submitted questionnaire with account on homepage

Tags: javascript, php, sql, google-forms

I have a homepage with customers with their own accounts. I want to make a small questionnaire (for example after a video). When the customer submit his questionnaire, how can I connect it with his account? Like checking all his submitted questionnaires if I click on his profile.

I could do it with Google Forms for example BUT I cannot track who submitted it. It is possible if they fill out their email addresses. This is the thing I don't want. Is it somehow possible to track it with their current existing accounts? If yes, can you provide me some links so I can look up.

**Rework question:**
It is NOT necessary to use Google Forms. It can be any 3rd tool to do a questionnaire (it should be free) or anything else. With account I mean a similar system like here stackoverflow with your own account. Mine is mRozwold and it was created by me and not by an admin. It is just in MY CASE that I call them customers, so sry for the confused question.

Comment: Does Google Forms have a Session?

Comment: I am not quite sure. I can embed Google Forms on the homepage but I dont think that I can somehow access anything from there.

Comment: The only way that a Google Form can automatically collect the email address of the user, is if the user is within the same "domain" (Paid Account or Organizational account)  A Google Form can not automatically collect non-Google email addresses, or email address of users outside of a domain.  It's not clear from your question what you mean by customers "with their own accounts?"  Do you mean customer accounts that *you* set up?

Comment: I reworked my question.